# make a bot automatically update his pfp when discord server logo changes in Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

so i've tried making my bot automatically change his profile picture whenever a certain server he's in changes their server icon, so that he takes the server icon and puts it as a pfp, it's a private bot so there's no spam but i was wondering if it could be possible, i asked everywhere and nobody knew.

ive asked everywhere if it was possible and nobody really knew how to, i tried myself but as i'm a beginner it was even worse as i mess up fast. could anyone give me an code for it?

Comment: You can use the [on_guild_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild#discord.on_guild_update) and change the pfp if the guild's icon has changed.

Comment: i kinda understand what it is but i'm a beginner and i'm very bad at this, so can you give me the code for it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(YOUR_TOKEN_HERE)


@bot.event
async def on_guild_update(before: discord.Guild, after: discord.Guild):
    if before.icon != after.icon:
        await bot.user.edit(avatar=YOUR_URL_HERE)
```

Comment: does it changes it to the server icon or it changes to a pfp i set? because i want it to change his pfp to the server pfp

Comment: It changes the bot's pfp. If you want to change ur bot's pfp to the guild's pfp. Put the URL as `after.guild.icon.url`. Beware that `AttributeError` maybe raised if the icon was removed, ie, `after.icon` will be `None`.